# VBA Check if cells of a row consist of same text continously

Tags: excel, vba

i have a row of 24 cells having value Null and "ON". i  want to write a macro to  check this row if it contains 2 block of 6 "ON" continuously. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify if there needed to be any empty cells in between the blocks, or if more than 2 blocks of 6 consecutive ONs fulfills the criteria aswell. I have assumed only 2 blocks fulfills the criteria and that the two blocks can be after each other, i.e. 12 ONs in a row.

```
Function CheckForOn()

    Dim myRange
    Dim numberOfONs
    Dim numberOfBlocks
    Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:X1")
    numberOfONs = 0
    numberOfBlocks = 0

    For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.Value = "ON" Then
            numberOfONs = numberOfONs + 1
            If numberOfONs = 6 Then
                numberOfBlocks = numberOfBlocks + 1
                numberOfONs = 0
            End If
        Else
            numberOfONs = 0
        End If
    Next cell

    If numberOfBlocks = 2 Then
        CheckForOn = True
    Else
        CheckForOn = False
    End If

End Function
```